Cold water pipe hammering
As soon as the cold water is turned on in the shower, the pipe starts a hammering sound, if someone flushes the toilet however, during the hammering, it goes away. Now this only happens if someone turns the cold water on full blast right away, if you slowly turn it on, you will never hear this. What’s weird though, if I shut the water source off to the toilet, it doesn’t do it at all either. The house has those pressurized toilets when we bought it 10 years ago. I feel like it’s gotta be something with the toilet since if I isolate that, there is no hammering affect.

installing a water hammer preventer will probably fix this.
